# Finding the title of a PDF with Python

Tags: python, pdf

I have a  PDF file, and I would like to extract its title into a string. By title I don't mean the title in the metadata, but the actual title written in the document. For example, from [here](https://satonlinecourse.collegeboard.org/SR/digital_assets/assessment/pdf/0833A611-0A43-10C2-0148-CC8C0087FB06-F.pdf) I'd like to get "Official SAT® Practice Test 2014-15"

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you define what constitutes a title?  Largest text on the first page?  First line of text?

Comment: Can you reliably extract *any* text out of your PDF? Can you reliably extract its associated font size? Asking for "any way" is a bit broad.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't KNOW whether I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a look at [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html). Essentially you can load your PDF programatically. Then you will need to do some type of analysis to figure out how to extract the title. Perhaps you try using the first until new line break, or some type of algorithmic approach. I recommend using a large set of PDFs where you know the title, and run your program against them to test to see if you successfully detect the title. Then you can use that code to process the PDFs where you don't know the title. This technique is commonly referred to as using a training set.